# CSS 2 column layout with variable heights and different mobile/desktop layout

Tags: html, css, sass

Is there a way to build a 2 column layout so that each item can be of dynamic height and has a different order on mobile [as can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aKVe.png)?

I've been able to partially achieve this by wrapping the left and right elements in their own `div` however, there doesn't seem to be a way to re-order elements outside of their column `div` for the mobile view:

```css
.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / 1fr;
}

.column-left {
  align-self: start;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.column-right {
  align-self: start;
  grid-row: 2;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .parent {
    grid-template: auto / repeat(8, 1fr);
  }
  
  .column-left {
    grid-column: 1 / 4;
    grid-row: auto;
  }
  
  .column-right {
    grid-column: 4 / 9;
    grid-row: auto;
  }
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#item-a {
  height: 140px;
  background-color: red;
}

#item-b {
  height: 180px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#item-c {
  height: 220px;
  background-color: green;
}

#item-d {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="column-left">
    <div id="item-a" class="item">A</div>
    <div id="item-b" class="item">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-right">
    <div id="item-c" class="item">C</div>
    <div id="item-d" class="item">D</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be helpful for a question such as this if you set up the code and linked to a codepen or the like so that anyone trying to help could get right into it without having to do that step first.

Comment: If possible please put your code into an SO snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example rather than on an outside site.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a minimal reproducible example to my question as a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can in css since you want to move an item from a column to an other one. It may not be what you want but this is the solution I found :

```css
.container{
  width:100px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border:1px solid black;
}

#a{
  background-color:red;
}
#b{
  background-color:blue;
}
#c{
  background-color:green;
}
#d{
  background-color:yellow;
}

.item{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

.order-1{
  order: 1;
}
.order-2{
  order: 2;  
}
.order-3{
  order: 3;  
}
.order-4{
  order: 4;  
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .item{
    width:50%;
  }
  .order-lg-1{
    order: 1;
  }
  .order-lg-2{
    order: 2;
  }
  .order-lg-3{
    order: 3;  
  }
  .order-lg-4{
    order: 4;  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="a" class="item order-2 order-lg-1">A <br> A</div>
  <div id="b" class="item order-3 order-lg-3">B</div>
  <div id="c" class="item order-1 order-lg-2">C <br> C <br> C</div>
  <div id="d" class="item order-4 order-lg-4">D <br> D </div>
</div>
```

Check Full Page to see the difference in larger screen